# how to retrieve data from array list in desired manner

Tags: java

I have to take input from a user in a single line separated by commas. I have saved that input in an array list. Now I want to search that data in the manner below ... How can it be done?

I want to search in this manner:

Enter any alphabet from A – Z:

```
<A>
```

Please select a range:

Aa-Ac | Ad-Ad | Ae-Al | Am-Am | An-Ao | Ap-Ar | As-At | Au-Aw | Ax-Az

```
<Aa-Ac>
```

A-> Aa-Ac:

now data with in this range will be printed.
Here is what I have already done

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.lang.model.element.Element;

public class practice {
     static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(" Welcome to Your Own A-Z Drug Guide");
     System.out.println("Press 1 to enter new drugs");
     System.out.println("Press 2 for browsing");
     System.out.println("Press 3 for exiting");
     int choice = sc.nextInt();

     switch(choice){
     case 1:
     System.out.println("Please enter drugs name");
     String drugsName = sc.next(); 
     String[] drugs = drugsName.split("\\,");
     Arrays.sort(drugs);
     List<String> list = Arrays.asList(drugs);
     System.out.println(list);  
     System.out.println(matches(list, "aa"));
     break;
     case 2:
     System.out.println(" Enter any alphabet from A – Z:");
     String alphabet = sc.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Please select a range");
     if(alphabet=="a"){
     System.out.println("Aa-Ac | Ad-Ad | Ae-Al | Am-Am | An-Ao | Ap-Ar | As-At | Au-Aw | Ax-Az");
     String range = sc.nextLine();  
    //System.out.println(matches(list, "aa"));
     break;

     }
    }

 }




public static List<String> matches (List<String> dataList, String matchStr){
      List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
      if (matchStr != null) {
        matchStr = matchStr.toLowerCase();
        for(String d : dataList){
              if (d.toLowerCase().contains(matchStr)) {
                result.add(d);
              }
            }
      }
      return result;
}
}
```

Comment: **Don't** `alphabet=="a"`. **Do** `"a".equals(alphabet)`.

Comment: ok thanks i will do it, need some more help about searching in a particular range.

Comment: I know you say ArrayList, but how about looking into a trie data structure?  This is quite natural for a problem searching prefixes of a word.  You can search for all a, or at the next level all aa.  So you browse the appropriate levels as selected by the user.